# "No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions" during SQL Server setup on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I've been following the instructions Microsoft provides to install SQL Server  on an Ubuntu server here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu

I do have sudo access but not sure if anything else would be needed.

All of the steps work fine up until I run `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`, where I encounter the error:

> No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions

followed by:

> Setting up Microsoft SQL Server
>
> Enter the new SQL Server system administrator password:
>
> Confirm the new SQL Server system administrator password:
>
> find: ‘/usr/share/doc/google-chrome-stable’: Permission denied
>
> Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the
>   system.
>
> ```
>   Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
>
>   turn off this notice.
> ```
>
> No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
>
> Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the
>   system.
>
> ```
>   Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
>
>   turn off this notice.
> ```
>
> No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
>
> tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
>
> ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog*': No such file or
>   directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/exception.log': No such file or
>   directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDu*.txt': No such file or
>   directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDu*.mdmp': No such file or
>   directory
>
> ls: cannot access '/var/opt/mssql/log/system_health*': No such file or
>   directory
>
> nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
>
> Failed to change system administrator password with error code 1.
>
> Please check the setup log in
>   /var/opt/mssql/log/setup-20170403-182345.log
>
> for more information.

I have provided all of the log files in a .tar since there were a bunch within it, and I didn't want to have to make 7 or 8 pastebin links. If any other information is needed let me know!

https://ufile.io/1b232

Thanks, Eric

EDIT 1:
setup-20170403-182345.log output

```
This is an evaluation version.  There are [161] days left in the evaluation period.
Reading dump control values from /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf
===============================================
              Mini dump type: miniplus (2)
Capturing mini and full dump: true
===============================================
Capturing core dump and information for sqlservr (pid 9513)...
Capturing dump with paldumper
Capturing dump with gdb
SQL Log Directory /var/opt/mssql/log
Packaging core dump and information into compressed files.
Core dump and information will be written to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_18_23_46.9513 and logs in /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_18_23_46.9513.log
```

core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_18_23_46.9513.log output:

```
Building core dump and log files archive
Compressing core.sqlservr.9513.temp into /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_18_23_46.9513
pbzip2 is not installed, using bzip2
Building log files only archive
Compressing core.sqlservr.9513.temp into /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_18_23_46.9513
pbzip2 is not installed, using bzip2
Archive written to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_18_23_46.9513.tbz2
```

The .tbz2 file it mentions is the one I have linked above with ufile.

EDIT 2:

I can run `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf start-service` and the server will start, but will close not too long after.

WHEN RUNNING

```
eric@Flora:~$ sudo systemctl status mssql-server
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-03 21:54:48 EDT; 5s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 20466 (generate-core.s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─20463 sh /opt/mssql/bin/compress-dump.sh core.sqlservr.20283.temp /var/opt/mssql/log/co
           ├─20464 tar cjf /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_21_54_25.20283.work -C core.s
           ├─20465 bzip2
           ├─20466 /bin/bash /opt/mssql/bin/generate-core.sh sqlservr 20479 /opt/mssql/bin /var/opt/
           ├─20479 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─20529 sleep 5

Apr 03 21:54:48 Flora systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Apr 03 21:54:48 Flora sqlservr[20466]: This is an evaluation version.  There are [161] days left in
Apr 03 21:54:48 Flora sqlservr[20466]: Reading dump control values from /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf
Apr 03 21:54:49 Flora sqlservr[20466]: ===============================================
Apr 03 21:54:49 Flora sqlservr[20466]:               Mini dump type: miniplus (2)
Apr 03 21:54:49 Flora sqlservr[20466]: Capturing mini and full dump: true
Apr 03 21:54:49 Flora sqlservr[20466]: ===============================================
Apr 03 21:54:49 Flora sqlservr[20466]: Capturing core dump and information for sqlservr (pid 20479).
Apr 03 21:54:49 Flora sqlservr[20466]: Capturing dump with paldumper
Apr 03 21:54:52 Flora systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

AFTER ABOUT 1 MIN

```
eric@Flora:~$ sudo systemctl status mssql-server
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-03 21:57:52 EDT; 10s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
  Process: 21721 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 21721 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─21920 sh /opt/mssql/bin/compress-dump.sh core.sqlservr.21723.temp /var/opt/mssql/log/co
           ├─21921 tar cjf /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.04_03_2017_21_57_29.21723.work -C core.s
           └─21922 bzip2

Apr 03 21:57:52 Flora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 03 21:57:52 Flora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 03 21:57:52 Flora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling resta
Apr 03 21:57:52 Flora systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
Apr 03 21:57:52 Flora systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 03 21:57:52 Flora systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```